# Why is the conduction band of Si not monotonic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics

A typical band structure of silicon is shown in the picture. If we consider a subband of the conduction band within the first Brillouin zones, we can clearly see that this subband is not monotonic. It involves more than one local minima or maxima points within the first zone, which confuse me a lot.

What the physical reason that causes the non-monotonic feature of the conduction band?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by monotonically, and why should it be?

Comment: I mean that the curve for conduction band involves more than one local minima or maxima point within first zone, which confuse me. As along with the increase of crystal momentum, the energy as I see have no reason to drop, how can electron in conduction band lose energy while occupy a higher crystal momentum?

Comment: Because they are not free electrons - they occupy Bloch states which are a function of the periodicity of the crystal. Phonon bands aren't generally monotonic either. In both cases, there is no physical reason to attempt to require that higher momenta states have a higher energy. That is, perhaps, left over from classical mechanics courses. This is quantum-based solid state physics.

Comment: Also note that crystal momentum  is not simply increasing from left to right, but that the x axis is following a path around the [Brillouin zone](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=silicon+brillouin+zone&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB703GB703&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCiYee-oXSAhXJKsAKHYsmDBIQsAQIIg&biw=1920&bih=950) in 3D. The $L$, $\Lambda$, $\Gamma$, etc mark where the path reaches the high symmetry points of the zone.